# How to increament property value in google datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have this entity in google data store:

```
{
   count: 10;
}
```

Is there a way in datastore in which i can increment the `count` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually modify the property in the DataStore section of the Developer's Console: https://console.developers.google.com/datastore

Or you can have an app programatically read, modify and save the property's value. The exact methods depends on the app language you choose, you have language-specific tutorials and documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs.

Comment: I meant to ask how to do it programmatically. As we have following syntax in MongoDB
    {
         $set: {<property>: <new Value>}
    }